# How do I created a nested object from a flat list using Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested, underscore.js, grouping

Give `input` and `order`:

```
input = [
    {
        "top": "peach", 
        "middle": "monkey",
        "bottom": "blue"
    },
    {
        "top": "peach", 
        "middle": "monkey",
        "bottom": "red"
    },
    {
        "top": "peach", 
        "middle": "cat",
        "bottom": "brown"
    },
    {
        "top": "peach", 
        "middle": "cat",
        "bottom": "black"
    },
    {
        "top": "peach", 
        "middle": "dog",
        "bottom": "purple"
    }
];

order = ["top", "middle", "bottom"];
```

Generate a "nested" `output`:

```
output =     {
    "name": "peach",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "monkey",
            "children": [
                { "name": "blue" },
                { "name": "red" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "cat",
            "children": [
                { "name": "brown" },
                { "name": "black" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "dog",
            "children": [
                { "name": "purple" }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I know it has something to do with `_.groupBy()` and using recursion, but I can't wrap my head around it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recursive solution which uses **[groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy)** on each item in the order list:

```
var nestedGroup = function(list, order) {

    if( _.isEmpty(order)) return [];

    var groups = _.groupBy(list, _.first(order));

    return _.map(groups, function(children, key){
        var group = {
            name: key,
            children: nestedGroup(children, _.rest(order))
        };

        return _.isEmpty(group.children) ? _.omit(group, 'children') : group;
    });
}

var groups = nestedGroup(input, order);
```

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller('MyController', function( $scope ) {
  
 var input = [
     {
         "top": "peach", 
         "middle": "monkey",
         "bottom": "blue"
     },
     {
         "top": "peach", 
         "middle": "monkey",
         "bottom": "red"
     },
     {
         "top": "peach", 
         "middle": "cat",
         "bottom": "brown"
     },
     {
         "top": "peach", 
         "middle": "cat",
         "bottom": "black"
     },
     {
         "top": "peach", 
         "middle": "dog",
         "bottom": "purple"
     }
 ];

 var order = ["top", "middle", "bottom"];

 var nestedGroup = function(list, order) {

  if( _.isEmpty(order)) return [];

  var groups = _.groupBy(list, _.first(order));

  return _.map(groups, function(children, key){
   var group = {
    name: key,
    children: nestedGroup(children, _.rest(order))
   };

   return _.isEmpty(group.children) ? _.omit(group, 'children') : group;
  });
 }

 var groups = nestedGroup(input, order);
  
    $scope.groups = groups;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
  <p>{{groups || json}}</p>
</div>
```